# How can I set the id in mongoose to have only numbers instead of a string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

By default mongoose stores in the object id a random string. I need the id to be only numbers. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) plugin, may be it covers your needs.

Comment: Thank you! That indeed helped!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to keep the  Object id that generates automatically using mongoose, but if you really want to change the id (I hope you mean _id). then you can try like this

```
let user= new Schema({ _id: Number, username:String, blah blah blah});
```

or you can disable the _id using this

```
let user= new Schema({ _id: Number, username:String, blah blah blah},{ _id: false });
```

if you want to create an additional field **"id"** by keeping the  **_id** then you can try this

```
let user= new Schema({ id: Number, username:String, blah blah blah});
```

just use the type Number as the type and that's all

Comment: I don't want to use the _id in the mongoose schema. I like how mongoose creates it's own id. I just want this id to be of type Number and not String. Is this possible?

Comment: yeah definitely.. check the answer again I have updated

Comment: I thought about it but i want only one _id. I dont want 2 fields with id.

Comment: then just don't mention any id in the schema and let the mongoose work its magic..